# MATLAB - Newton's Method to solve a system of nonlinear equations

Tags: matlab, newtons-method, function-handle

I'm trying to write a function that uses [Newton's Method to solve a system of nonlinear equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKmoM.jpg)

Function:

`[roots, count, resids, history] = Newtons(func,x0,tol`)

with the following inputs and outputs.

[image]

I'm struggling with creating the function handle (the first input) and using it in the main function as well as understanding and generating the `resids` and `history` outputs. I would really appreciate some help with this function.

What I've done/tried so far: (I'm relatively new to Matlab and believe it is totally wrong and not worth looking at)

```
% function handle for the first input (func)
function [f, J] = jacobian(f, x)
n=length(x); 
fx=f(x); 
step=1e-10; 

for i=1:n
   xstep = x;
   xstep(i)=x(i)+step;
   J(:,i)=(f(xstep)-fx)/step;
end
end

function [roots, count, resids, history] = Newtons(func,x0,tol)
func = @jacobian;

if nargin == 2
    tol = 10e-10;
end

MAXIT = 50;
xx = x0;
N = 0;
while N < 50
    JJ = func(2);

end
```

Comment: You don't need to define `func = ...` *inside* your function, that would defeat the point of it being an input! You should put your functions in separate files `jacobian.m` and `Newtons.m` (although maybe use a name differerent from `jacobian` because that is a built in function). You would then run this from a **script** file, where you define your function handle and call the function `Newtons`